# Qt/C++ (Pre-)Allocating large file

Tags: c++, qt, file-io

Is there a way of allocating a file with a determined size with Qt?

The reason is to avoid or minimize fragmentation. I don't want to zero-write a large file (unwanted overhead), but just allocate it from the file system.

I'd like a solution which works on Win/OSX/Linux. I know there are solutions depending on the file system in question for all these platforms, but digging up the solutions and testing on each platform takes some time.

Comment: usual idea is to:
1) open file for writing
2) seek to the desired end
3) close

problem is .. most of filesystems have 'sparse' file concept which still won't preallocate the space .. Writing with zeros is probably the only guaranteed way...

Comment: I guess that answers my question. Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't writing zeroes still create fragmentation? I was thinking torrent clients and virtual machine disks get allocated with minimal overhead using some file system function for avoiding fragmentation.

Comment: you could try as well those calls (if they are implemented): posix_fadvise/posix_fallocate

Comment: It would seem the `posix_fadvise` with `POSIX_FADV_SEQUENTIAL` as `advice` parameter is exactly what I was looking for, but with an Qt platform abstration in order to have it work under Windows aswell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about fragmentation, but Qt has `QFile::resize()` method which clearly pre-allocates (or truncates) the file. The process is fast - ~1s for 800MB on my machine, therefore the file is clearly not explicitly garbage-filled. Tested on Windows 7.

Comment: You're right! I filled my hard drive with 1GiB files in "no time". The interesting thing is Qt documentation states it will be filled with zeroes if bigger than current file size. Checked with a hex editor this is actually true, even while actually writing zeroes to over 100 GiB cannot occur this fast. This must be a feature of the file system under windows, hope it works on Linux and OSX too!

Comment: @hg. please share your findings here with the rest of community for future reference (:

Comment: Should I use `Answer You Question` or should I edit my original question? I'll post my results when I get to test it on Linux.

Comment: I'm not sure about fragmentation, but the same thing works on Linux on ext4 as well. I accidentally was able to allocate 700K 1GiB files with 50Gib free space, which leads me to think there is not much allocation going on in the actual file system, but merely an entry to state file size and any reading returns only zeroes.

Comment: Windows has the _explicit concept_ of preallocated file storage; it keeps _two_ "file sizes", namely "file data valid up to size `X`" and "file has allocated blocks up to size `Y`" (well, three really - file size, valid size, and number of allocated blocks). They don't necessarily match, but having two allows Windows filesystems to preallocate data blocks without having to clear them on allocation. On UN*X, you'll get a sparse file from `QFile::resize`, so while that's fast, it _allocates nothing_.